# Error en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente problema con javascript[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el codigo

```js
$(function(){
 $.post("../php/cargar_marcas.php", function(data){
  $("#marca").html(data);
 });
});
```

La verdad así lo he hecho siempre, el script de php funciona correctamente, pero no se por que me esta marcando error en la primera linea, he hecho otras funciones así y no ahí problema, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: es por que no estas referenciando bien el archivo js llamado marcos.js fíjate en el head o donde estas haciendo las referencias de los archivos .JS

Comment: Hola The Vicious este es mi codigo HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css">
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ya añadiste Jquery? no es asi incluyelo en el head asi y ala etiqueta script borrale algunas cosas dejala asi `<script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang = "es"> 
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/plantilla_gral.css"> 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "../js/marcas.js"></script>
```

Comment: Errores tontos, gracias.

Comment: no de hay de que siempre pasa XD